# Revision History is Bass-Ackwards on some posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list

I edited [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6638881/331508) and then checked the [Revision History](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6638881/revisions).  It showed this:

[image]

The revision order is wrong and it looks like I asked the question!

Clearing the cache and reloading did not help.
Other edits I made, some just minutes earlier, show a sensible history.

Also, the second edit is hours in the future!  See: [Time travel on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98014/time-travel-on-so)

**ETA:** Here's [a second question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6638953/331508) with [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6638953/revisions).

Comment: I love the 'Edited **in** three hours'

Comment: @M. Tibbits, oddly enough the time-travel seems intermittent when I reload that page.  Seconds ago, the times were back to the past, but the order and attribution was still reversed!?

Comment: When I view [the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6638881/revisions) you are listed as asking the question, but it doesn't show up in your [Asked questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/331508/brock-adams) (as it shouldn't).  It shows up as being asked [by user802370](http://stackoverflow.com/users/802370/user802370) (as it should)

Comment: The purpose in asking was to rule out simple things like, are you four hours east of the prime merdian -- perhaps it's a date thing and not a time thing -- but being in PDT...  I'll delete my comment -- feel free to delete yours.  Which browser?

Comment: Firefox, in the main.  Checked with Chrome, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the strange Revision CreationDates have been fixed manually for Post Histories that had a creation date < the post creation date.

Comment: Thanks!   Just for giggles, about how many were there?

Comment: I found 6 - 5 were your edits @Brock, you must be lucky

Comment: I have always been "lucky" like that, but I'd guess it was more likely that I was the only one doing much editing during the off-hours when this glitch struck.

Comment: All the answer, comment, and question timestamps were affected also.  I'm not sure that manual fixes will be feasible.

Answer (score 11):

This was the result of a time-sync issue from one of our web servers (one we still can't fully explain, possibly forgot it was in UTC (Zulu) time like the rest of our servers, briefly)...but it's corrected now and shouldn't be happening anymore.

Comment: But it still show the question as Asked by Brock, while it's not.

Comment: @Shadow - yep, it's indeed a bug, not quite sure how we'll deal with this though - it's not a very straightforward thing to fix so we'll need to be careful in how we correct the data here.