# Time travel on SO?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, timestamps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Revision History is Bass-Ackwards on some posts.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98013/revision-history-is-bass-ackwards-on-some-posts)

I seem to be seeing questions and answers **before** they are actually posted. As you can see, in Exhibit A, I see a question and its answers from 5 hours in the future. What is interesting here is that they aren't shown as negative time offsets, but "in x hours".

[image: Exhibit A]

In Exhibit B, you can see negative seconds for future times.

[image: Exhibit B]

How is this possible?

I am in UTC -7 (Arizona Time), and my system clock is synchronized with time.nist.gov

Comment: Possibly related to [this ¿brilliant? post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98013/148310).   ;)

Comment: When asked if he's having problems, he says "not yet", so maybe it's legit ;)

Comment: Here is the [question mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639006).  The times look fine here -- Ubuntu synced using ntpd.

Comment: What is your OS & timezone?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit. Mountain Standard (Arizona), as mentioned.

Comment: +1 for having one of my answers... yes, i am in the future, UTC+11 to be exact. I'm puzzled about the 5hr figure though, I am 5 hours ahead of Indonesia/Vietnam/etc, and about 16 hrs ahead of you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Nick Craver's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98013/revision-history-is-bass-ackwards-on-some-posts/98047#98047), one of the web servers got (way) out of sync.  "It's corrected now and shouldn't be happening anymore."