# Back to the future

Tags: bug, status-completed, timestamps

We have [Was a question asked in the future?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36591/was-a-question-asked-in-the-future) recurring, but more significantly.  Seems it also happened [last week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98014/time-travel-on-so-closed)

I see "asked in 4 hours" and "answered in 5 hours" all over the site.  Is this a browser-specific bug?  I'm using Chrome, latest version, on Windows 7.

[image]

Now that the clock is back to running right, we have a number of comments and answers which carry a timestamp 5 hours too early, and hence appear out of order (and users might think the wrong answer was the earliest).

Comment: Related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98013/revision-history-is-bass-ackwards-on-some-posts ?

Comment: Here's the post in the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720870/how-do-i-efficiently-simulate-a-grid-of-static-rectangles-in-a-physics-engine -- seems fixed now?

Comment: @Jon: I hesitate to say **fixed**, exactly, when all comments and answers left during the broken interval are misdated and appear out of their correct sort order.

Comment: You're right -- I didn't notice that.

Comment: Errr.... it doesn't help that one of the answerers is editing and removing/adding new comments.

Comment: @Jon: Here's another example of misdated comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721431/effect-of-explicit-on-static-upcasting/6721467#6721467 (aschepler's comment is currently dated before the question and answer)

Comment: Perhaps the Sci-Fi site is growing too much

Comment: @belisarius It's not our fault. It wasn't our fault. It willan not haventa forewhen bean our fault. What you saw was swamp gas from a weather balloon was trapped in a thermal pocket and reflected the light from Venus. Move along.

Comment: @Gilles Glad to hear that. I thought it could something weird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The wombats in one of our servers are getting tired for an inexplicable reason causing it to lose time sync (gah!) and thus causing these issues. We are in the process of finding the defective wombat and ... taking care of them.