# Bug in comment timestamp

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, timestamps

Every once in a while (2X a week or so), when I submit a comment, the timestamp says that I submitted it "in 0 seconds" instead of the usual "0 secs ago".  This isn't a huge problem, but if it can easily be fixed, I'd like it to be.

[image: bug?]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Back to the future](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98816/back-to-the-future)

Comment: [According to Geoff](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/250/sort-of-bug-in-0-seconds-instead-of-0-seconds-ago-or-similar), it should have been fixed.

Comment: Last month.  I see, but it hasn't been fixed, at least not on ELU.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am changing it so that time differences of 4 seconds or less will no longer display as

> … in 3 seconds
>
> … 2 seconds ago

but rather

> … just now

because really, what is the point of such absurd precision when we're talking about something that happened *seconds ago?*

Comment: Exactly, compared to Reddit, which cares enough to tell us how many milliseconds it took between submitting a post and a page refresh.