# Why was the editing thing changed into "Edited just now"?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bug in comment timestamp](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104921/bug-in-comment-timestamp)

Usually, when editing a question or an answer, what happens when you click the "save edits" button, is that the screen reverts back to normal, with your name appearing at the bottom of the post, as well as the words over it :

"Edited *0 seconds ago*"

Now, however, it is :

"Edited *just now*"

What's the reason for this?

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104921/bug-in-comment-timestamp

Answer (score 3):

Because some complain... [Jeff wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104921/bug-in-comment-timestamp/104939#104939):

> I am changing it so that time differences of 4 seconds or less will no longer display as [...] but rather
>
> > … just now
>
> because really, what is the point of such absurd precision when we're talking about something that happened *seconds* ago?