# "You can accept an answer just now"

Tags: bug, status-completed, timestamps, wording

It looks like that text like "2 seconds ago" has been changed to "just now". This makes sense with time that has ended, like the time of posting questions/answers/comments.

When trying to accept an answer one also gets this time text in a message, like this:

> You can accept an answer in 30 seconds

However, with the "just now" update the wording in this case has become a little weird:

[image: You can accept an answer just now]

It says it's possible to accept an answer 'just now' but in fact it's *not* possible at the moment you get the message.

Although this may sound like nitpicking, I'd like to propose changing it to something more meaningful.

Comment: Regression caused by [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104921/bug-in-comment-timestamp/104939#104939), possibly?

Comment: Good catch! I think most simple solution is to put back the old counter in this specific scenario so the user will know exactly when he can accept the answer.

Comment: Even if you _could_ accept at that point (not getting the message,) the message is entirely awkward anyway. What on earth has 'just' got to do with anything anyway, sounds as informal as slang. What's wrong with 'now' for _now_? Since we're talking of relative times, anything _after_ now has no comparison containing 'now.' (i.e _'2 minutes after 'just now''_)

Comment: "If you are reading this message, you can accept an answer."

Comment: Changing it to "now" isn't a bad idea; that would fix [this one](http://so.mrozekma.com/associations-check-back-just-now.png) as well

Comment: @Mr.D It indicates that the time is not *exactly* now, but rather in the near vicinity of now.  Using "just" that way is quite common and not informal.  "About now" would mean nearly the same thing but is more awkward, and "around now" seems too loose.  I like "just now" when shown on a post I just made.  In fact you can think of it as being short for "this post was just made now" or similar.

Comment: @Michael Would it? Still seems weird to me. The page should just refresh itself if it wants you to refresh it immediately.

Comment: @Matthew Well, giving you the error "you can accept an answer now" isn't great either, but at least it's grammatical

Comment: Please fix this immediately!

Comment: @Michael: Alternatively "just now" could only apply to short time differences in the past and "momentarily" could apply to short time differences in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing this so for *future* dates < 4 seconds it will be

> you can foo the bar **momentarily**

while for *past* dates < 4 seconds it will remain

> you fooed the bar **just now**

Comment: *Please* don't use "momentarily". To those of us not using American English that means "for a moment" (so then you'll get people asking why they can only accept an answer for a few seconds), please consider just using "in a moment" or "in a few seconds", which mean exactly what they say. (Sorry to move the comment, but this post is the newer, and probably more relevant, one)

Comment: I second @DMA and "in a few seconds" sounds better IMO.

Comment: I should say my point isn't against American English, but that "you can foo the bar momentarily" reads incorrectly to anyone using another form of the language (and so a sizeable(?) proportion of the site's users), while something like "you can foo the bar in a few seconds" should read correctly for *everyone*.

Comment: _'[Usage Note](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/momentarily): Momentarily is widely used in speech to mean "in a moment," as in The manager is on another line, but she'll be with you momentarily. This usage rarely leads to ambiguity since the intended sense can usually be determined on the basis of the tense of the verb and the context. Nonetheless, many critics hold that the adverb should be reserved for the senses "for a moment," and the extended usage is unacceptable to 59 percent of the Usage Panel.'_ Sometimes bells and whistles only serve to create noise.

Comment: @Mr.D tbh, I'm not sure if you're agreeing with my comment or making a point against it?

Answer (score 14):

The current logic is to use the phrase "just now" for [time intervals less than four seconds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104921/bug-in-comment-timestamp/104939#104939) in duration.

If it isn't too much trouble to implement, I think the user should just be allowed to accept the answer (the error message is *not* displayed) if the timer is within five seconds of expiring anyway.

Extra points for doing it this way on any timer that inhibits a user action (except for rate limiters like the timer to slow down posting of multiple comments).

Comment: I know this has been discussed over and over, but I would give the extra points if this is done on any timer that inhibits a user action, _especially_ for rate limiters like the timer to slow down flagging of multiple comments.