# Incorrect use of the word 'momentarily' when accepting answers

Tags: discussion, wording

I got an answer to a question very shortly after posting it on StackOverFlow, and went to accept it, but got a message along the lines of "you can't accept this question for 4 minutes".

I tried again approx 4 minutes later, and got a message something like 'You can accept this answer momentarily'.

Not to be a pedant, but 'momentarily' means 'for a moment' not 'in a moment', so saying you can accept the answer momentarily is incorrect - it should really say something like 'You can accept this answer in a moment'.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/momentarily

Comment: For a bit of background: [“You can accept an answer just now”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106067/162705)

Comment: Thanks - I really should have searched a bit before posting

Comment: You can't say "not to be a pedant" and then be pedantic... That's like saying "Don't be angry sweetie, but I got your sister pregnant. Wait! I said don't be angry!"

Comment: From the very link that you used, in the US it **does** mean "in a moment."

Comment: Point taken - but I was always taught that this was a common, yet incorrect, usage of the word.

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan, but if there's an easy-to-use [transpondian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transpondian) word, it's better than a U.S. one.

Comment: @Farseeker - that was deliberate.  I meant it in the same way someone says "I don't mean to be offensive" just before they say something really offensive to you.

Comment: Why not RSN - real soon now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[From the very same entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/momentarily):

> ### momentarily
>
> 1. In a momentary manner; for a moment or instant.
> 2. **(US) In a moment or very soon; at any moment.**
> 3. Progressively; moment-by-moment.
>
> Many speakers object to the use of momentarily in the sense of “in a moment” rather than “for a moment”, since this is inconsistent with the meaning of momentary; nonetheless, this use is quite common in North America, and is particularly associated with airlines, such as “we will be landing momentarily”. In place of momentarily, many speakers prefer the terms presently, soon or the phrase “in a moment”, for this sense of “in a moment”.

Tell you what. You accept this, and we won't auto-correct *colour* to *color*.

Comment: Why would anyone want to *introduce* typos?

Comment: Wait, are you telling me that currently SO *does* auto-correct colour to color?  I can't decide if I find that awesome or terrible (leaning towards awesome since I'm American).

Comment: Not sure what they call it in Ashley Judd Land, @random, but here in 'murrica we call that a *"usage error"*, and it isn't one...

Comment: Ok - so I've gotten used to seeing 'colour' spelled 'color', 'authorise' spelled 'authorize', so I'll just have to get used to seeing 'momentarily' and not think that it means 'for a moment'.

Comment: I'd understand if you want to accept tvanfosson's answer. "You may accept this answer anon". Beautiful.

Comment: _Color_ and _colour_ you can't get around: one is American and the other Ukogbanian. But if there's an easy-to-use [transpondian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transpondian) word to use instead of _momentarily_, why not?

Comment: To be perfectly honest with you, @msh, I'm fine with "presently". It's a little bit up there on the hoity-toity scale for the US, but "momentarily" isn't that far below it. I'm just noting that the latter isn't incorrect, just regional. Now, if we can deal with "canceled" vs. "cancelled".

Comment: OK - so I guess I was a bit hasty with this whole question and didn't read the link properly - and shouldn't have called the usage 'incorrect'.  Sorry about that.  However @msh210 makes a good point, and I do like the word 'anon' (even if it is a little hoity-toity sounding) so might change my accepted answer if you really don't mind, @Michael?

Comment: @StanK: _Anon_? I thought that was a joke answer. Who uses _anon_? Plus, anyone used to the Wikimedia sites, at least, will think "You can accept this answer anon" is calling him an anonymous user. _Presently_ is good; _in a moment_ is clearer, and precisely as many characters as _momentarily_.

Comment: @msh - actually now that you point out that 'in a moment' has the same number of characters as 'momentarily', this seems to be the best answer. The meaning should be perfectly clear to all English speakers.

Comment: Yes, "in a moment" is better, though less... *interesting*... than "anon" (I was being silly, it's not commonly accepted), or "presently".

Answer (score 11):

Because we really ought to improve both our grammar and our vocabularies.

> ### anon
>
> adverb (SOON) - /əˈnɒn/
>
> #### [Definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anon)
>
> 1. in a short time; soon.
> 2. at another time.
> 3. Archaic . at once; immediately.

Comment: Or simply "soon"!

Answer (score 7):

If we're sticking with adverbs, the moment in the sun dances with:

> ### presently
>
> adverb (SOON) - /ˈprez.ənt.li/
>
> #### [Definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/presently_2)
>
> **old-fashioned** soon; not at the present time but in the future, after a short time
>
> > *The room was hot and presently her eyes grew heavy and she began to feel sleepy.*

Comment: Or how about just being very explicit about it?  `You can do X in [about] Y minutes.`

Comment: @Jeff, reread the question, which is about the last moments.

Answer (score -1):

> Not to be a pedant, but 'momentarily' means 'for a moment' not 'in a moment'

No, it means either.

> so saying you can accept the answer momentarily is incorrect - it should really say something like 'You can accept this answer in a moment'.

so *you're* incorrect.

Not to be a pedant.