# Momentarily in comments

Tags: support, user-interface

Related: [Momentarily when accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106208/incorrect-use-of-the-word-momentarily-when-accepting-answers)

The English on this site is usually pretty good.  I think comments just say "momentarily" now, as soon as you submit them.  That doesn't sound right:

[image]

"Just now" worked better.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106297/momentarily-is-being-used-on-the-mobile-site-where-just-now-should-have-remai

Comment: Do you remember if this happened as soon as the comment was posted, and/or did you see it when refreshing the page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually a clock skew issue -- you are seeing comments "before" they existed according to the server clocks.

Comment: One way of dealing with this would be to have separate conversions for timestamps which are always in the past, such as the posting times of comments. This conversion would always treat future dates as "now".

Comment: Yeah I have seen this before. It was like SO was able to predict what question people are going to ask :)