# Comments showing "momentarily" instead of "just now" again

Tags: bug, comments, timestamps, wording, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Momentarily in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106410/momentarily-in-comments)

I just got this on Android Enthusiasts:

[image: screenshot]

Unless this has changed again (and to something that doesn't make sense), it should be "just now" instead of "momentarily".

It may be related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106297/momentarily-is-being-used-on-the-mobile-site-where-just-now-should-have-remai (see Tim Stone's comment) but this is the first time I've had this happen on the non-mobile site, and it was happening consistently on the mobile site.

As per the comment below, this doesn't happen consistently.  I'm *wondering* if it's showing "just now" for 0 seconds, and "momentarily" for negative seconds.  Negative seconds are much more rare due to how closely time is normally synced, which would explain why it's rarely seen.

Comment: Testing: cannot reproduce here, got "just now".

Comment: I've seen this recently (as in, earlier this week).

Comment: See also [Momentarily in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106410) (possible duplicate).

Comment: @HendrikVogt Indeed a dupe, thanks.