# About page question was answered over a year before it was asked

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tour

Note: This is NOT an actual SO question. It is a demo question on the About page. Not a duplicate of [Back To The Future](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98816/back-to-the-future).

The [About](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page for StackOverflow has a question animation in it to demonstrate how the Q&A here works.

[image]

The question was asked on September 10th, 2012. However, one of the answers is from February 7th, 2011.

If this is intentional, I believe the user's name must be changed to Jon Skeet, as we all know he's the only one who can [answer a question before it is asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9135/187954).

Comment: That's just how fast you get an answer on SO! The only implausible part is that there is no answer by Jon Skeet there.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Edited post to request answerer's name to be changed to Jon Skeet for time travel reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the case for the [source question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358843/why-are-function-pointers-and-data-pointers-incompatible-in-c-c).

The ['time traveling' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4924728/100297) was given to an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924690/c-why-is-casting-from-void-pointer-to-function-pointer-undefined), before it was merged into this newer question. You can see that in the [answer history  page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4924728/revisions).

In fact, [5 of the answers there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358843/why-are-function-pointers-and-data-pointers-incompatible-in-c-c?answertab=oldest#tab-top) predate the question; all were merged from the same source question.

Comment: Ah I see. Its funny though that out of all the time travel less answers on that question, they picked one of the few that showed this date discrepancy for the About page of the entire site.