# The real fastest gun in the west

Tags: support, timestamps, tour

Are the questions in the **about** page taken from real posts?
If not, who designs them? 
Particularly, why does this specific answer have a date from before the question was asked?

> [image]

Comment: They're real questions, that one just happened to [have been merged](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12358843/revisions).

Comment: You may have better things to do with your time machine than answer SO questions over a year in advance.  Jerry doesn't.

Comment: @TimStone ...Well played sir.

Comment: I see you have the 3D free hand red circle extension...

Comment: @Lix I take my free hand circles very seriously

Comment: AFAIK in US some people use twisted date format, if the question was asked on 12-09-2010 and the answer is from 07-02-2011 it would make sense

Comment: Here in canada, it makes sense

Comment: The actual duplicate of this question: [About page question was answered over a year before it was asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168200/about-page-question-was-answered-over-a-year-before-it-was-asked)