# Remove "+1" comment from "about" page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, tour

I know it's pretty minor, but the `/about` page on Stack Overflow should be exemplary to some extent, right? I wouldn't mind seeing the "+1" from this comment removed.

[image]

Since this page is aimed at newcomers, I feel it sets a less than optimal example. Do we agree that "+1/-1" in a comment is useless, at best?

When I started using SO I actually thought it was *expected* to do this, only because I saw it so much, so I imitated others and left a lot of comments leading with "+1".

I know there is a difference between `"+1 Great answer"` and `"+1 but {useful information}"` but I think it would be worth changing this example.

Comment: *cue ironic +1 comments*

Comment: You could flag the [specific comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358843/why-are-function-pointers-and-data-pointers-incompatible-in-c-c#comment16599839_12358902) perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think you may have missed the point, and I'm fairly sure they aren't "hotlinked" (it's surely static HTML on that about page).

Comment: @WesleyMurch: The samples on the About page are taken from actual content (with the scores fudged).

Comment: @MartijnPieters The comment is fine, no reason to flag, but using it as an example isn't really. We should put our best face forward.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: See [About page question was answered over a year before it was asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168200) for another sample of a question being used for the about page.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So you're saying that if the OP deleted his comment it would be removed from the "about" page? I highly doubt it. In any case, that's not my point. The original content is fine, but I'm sure the Wizards at SE can remove those 2 characters in the about page.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: I am not entirely certain how the page samples are picked, but IIRC site moderators can pick examples to be shown. Picking a different sample comment is probably the better option here, but if the comment were to be *deleted* that'd also work. In this case, not a good idea, really as the comment is fine.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: We can't choose which sample comment gets displayed (I'm assuming they just pick the highest-scoring one that's visible).

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: but you *can* pick a post from which comments are picked?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: We pick a single question through which all example answers and comments are taken.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: right, and here the highest-voted comment has a small problem in that it isn't the best example of a good comment. Can the `+1` simply be edited out by a moderator? Slighly *less* drastic than deleting the comment.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Actually, I just did that, but that didn't seem to affect the about page. Not sure if the content is cached or stored for the about page, but it looks like another moderator just went and chose another question entirely.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: ... and it's changed back but the comment still retains the +1. Um...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Still caching, probably. Let's leave it be for a little while and see if it picks up the change.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: OK. (**No, Stack Exchange, I would not like to automatically move this to chat.**)

Comment: It its live (or cached live) I can't help feeling this gives one or two people a real opportunity for a truly huge rage quit

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: That was me.  I tried refreshing the question, but nothing happened.  In other news, the UI for that could use some love; when I detached the question, it disappeared from the top list of candidates, and I had to sift through a half-dozen pages to find it again and reattach it.

Comment: @RichardTingle: good luck getting an already upvoted question deleted without moderator help.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was more thinking editing your own question to "F*** stack exchange, you all **** with **** and **** your ****ing ****s

Comment: Who's thinking about rage quitting?  Over a +1?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Sounds almost more rational than most rage-quit reasons I've seen.

Comment: Man, that must be the mother of all caches.  Oh, well.

Comment: Maybe it's not cached. I bet they copy/pasted it to fabricate the question/comment.

Comment: @JoshC: Yeah, but if I switched it to some other question and then switched it back, then they must be storing the fabrication *somewhere.*

Comment: The example questions and answers on that page are only updated every so often. They are randomly selected after some unknown period of time. Soon enough, this answer will completely disappear from the page never to be seen again. So worrying about it isn't something we should really care about, IMO.

Comment: @animuson: So basically, you're saying that we could just select a different question, if we wanted to get rid of the +1 now.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm saying it will automatically change to something else whenever the system loads a new one. The examples aren't permanent.

Comment: @animuson: Yeah, but where's the fun in that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Everyone knows we don't like fun here. :P

Answer (score 0):

Super pedantic....

Does the +1 really matter?

Comment: 1+ For irony...