# Comments out of order

Tags: bug, comments, timestamps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Back to the future](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98816/back-to-the-future)

There is a bad time stamp on a comment I just recently made on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721149/enable-qlabel-to-shrink-even-if-it-truncates-text/6721379#6721379). The question was posted 2 hours ago, my answer was posted 1 hour ago and the OP posted a comment to my answer 38 minutes ago. Somehow, my comment to his indicates that it was made 5 hours ago.

Comment: related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98816/back-to-the-future , http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98013/revision-history-is-bass-ackwards-on-some-posts and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98014/time-travel-on-so.

Comment: I tried a search before posting but never thought to try the words "back to the future", "bass-ackwards" or "time travel" :)

Comment: @ArnoldSpence: That's fair enough. Just as a friendly note from someone who casts a *lot* of close votes: they shouldn't necessarily be taken as a comment on your inability to search. Lots of questions are difficult to find, especially on Meta. Those of us who are more familiar with the site have an easier time finding them. Please don't take offense to having a question closed or a possible duplicate pointed out. :-)

Comment: No offense taken at all. That comment was purely a humorous observation. The 1337 skills and dedication of the SO community never cease to amaze me.

Comment: Whenever you discover a recent issue, it's worth scanning the titles on the homepage -- at the time, the other question was in the top 5 questions. I do agree the title of the other question doesn't exactly make the issue obvious, though. :)