# Comment Timestamp is earlier than Answer Timestamp

Tags: bug, comments, timestamps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Back to the future](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98816/back-to-the-future)
>   [Comments out of order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98818/comments-out-of-order)

Check out the comments on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6721379/483520

Arnold's comment seems to be referring to Voo's, but the timestamps have it before both Voo's comment and the answer to which the comment applies.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Yes, the [timeline view](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6721149/timeline) for that question is mighty strange. The comment is made first, to both a question and an answer that does not exist. I don't know what might cause this.

Comment: Reminds me of a certain forum, where one could comment on threads that weren't made yet, by substituting the thread id. Look at me, look at me, I have a time-machine.

Comment: Weeeird! Interestingly, the comment was supposedly written at 21:13 the previous day, which *could* be exactly 5 hours before the actual time it may have been written (2:13 UTC would make a lot of sense, it being a reply to one made at 2:12). The user resides in Canada, which has a UTC-5 time zone. Being able to mess with post times through some crazy time zone setting would be *such* a freakishly cool bug to do shenanigans with. Any chance of sweeping this under the rug before a dev sees it so we can look for it? :)

Answer (score 1):

If a mod converts an answer to a comment, the newly formed comment will have the same timestamp as the original answer.  (Though I'm unsure why a mod would convert it to a comment on another answer in the situation you linked to.)  Older answer gets converted to comment on newer answer = "time-traveling" comment.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense in this situation though. The comment was clearly a reply to a previous comment

Comment: @Pekka Hm...  funky.  Wombats were already marked "status-completed" so we know it's not that.  And the time period rules out ninja-edits.  I'm flumoxed...

Comment: The wombats probably just got off-schedule again. These things happen, especially if you forget to feed them. Or tire them out by awarding too many badges in a single day.